# ETC Folder Mac -- Admin Passwords Broken

Tags: macos, passwords, admin, macos-sierra

My DNS had problems, and a site told me to try to **remove all files in /private/etc.**  I did so, and it asked me to authenticate, and I did.

However, when it didn't help, I decided that it was better to put the files back.  It asked me to authenticate, but **ALL MY ADMIN PASSWORDS DON'T WORK**.  I'm using a school computer, so I've also tried the school's hidden master admin.

I think this has something to do with me deleting the files from the folder, which seems a bit ironic, and I don't know what to do because I can't put the files back without a password.

Thanks in advance.  I'm using MacOS Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

From the question it seems you have a backup. Thats great. You will need it.

## Why does my password no longer work?

`/private/etc` and `/etc` link to the same directory. You literally deleted all config files that the system needs to authenticate you. It may not even know your password anymore.

## How to fix

You won't be able to do that while running the system anymore. Shut it down, boot into a recovery mode and restore the files.

Here is a little hint for next time: Manually deleting many files from system locations (in macOS that is everything that is not `/Users` or `/Applications`) should throw red flags and make you uncomfortable. If the solution is to remove a top level folder from the system, it isn't a solution at all.

Comment: Yes, I was able to restart my computer in Sierra, and back up all the files (Apple did a little hacking to find files that weren't in my last backup).